# props are undefined when using mapStateToProps

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, mapstatetoprops

In my app I use mapStateToPros like that:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state:any) => {

   return {
    cardsAndBalance: state.cardsAndBalanceReducer
   }
}
```

In debug when I stop at `return` I can see that I have some data in state.

When I stop the app inside my useEffect function and check the `props`, the value of `props` is `undefined`

```
useEffect(() => {

    console.log('useEffect')
    
    let cardNumbers: number[] = []
    const myCards = props.cardsAndBalance.cards;

    if(myCards)
        myCards.forEach((card: Card) => cardNumbers.push(card.number))

    generatePaymentCodeForTavim(cardNumbers = [])
        .then((res:any) => {
            setBarCode(res.barCode);
        })
        .catch( (err:any) => {
            console.log("error: " + err)
            ToastAndroid.show("Error Occurrd - check logs", ToastAndroid.SHORT);
        })
}, [])
```

This is how I connect the component to the store:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PayWithTavimStep1);
```

And this is the whole component:

```
    const PayWithTavimStep1 = ({navigation}:{navigation:any}, props: any) => {
    
        const [barCode, setBarCode] = useState('')
    
        useEffect(() => {
    
            console.log('useEffect')
             //.......
        }, [])
    
        return (
            
            <View style={styles.container}>
               // Some views
            </View>
        )
    }
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PayWithTavimStep1
```

Why do the props are undefined when I stop the execution in useEffect?

Comment: try logging the props outside the `useEffect` or add them as dependencies to the `useEffect`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was passing two parameters to my component as such: `({navigation}:{navigation:any}, props: any)`. When it should have been `(props: any)` and now in my props I still have access to the navigation.